# Winforms AutoComplete Texbox Problem

Tags: winforms, textbox, autocomplete

Look this 
http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html

i have applied this for City Field textbox that displays the CityNames on Typing as Suggestion

I have taken a DataTable as DataSource which was pre-filled from Database.

I loop through DataTable and Add a CityNames to the AutoCompleteStringCollection

Now Problem is that How do i get Values that is(CityId) when Save My Record to the Database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Select method on DataTable to get rows matching the Textbox.Text

```
DT.Select("Name='" & TextBox1.Text & "'")
```